# AJAX запрос перестает работать в неактивном окне

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Здравствуйте! Собственно, вот такая проблема - есть у меня на одной страничке таймер, когда он приравнивается нулю, выполняется аякс запрос и таймеру добавляется еще несколько секунд.. И так по кругу.. Когда это окно и даже вкладка активны, то скрипт работает хорошо.. Стоит только переключить окно / вкладку скрипт останавливается на нуле и перестает работать

Скрипт, в принципе простой, работает на jQuery:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var sec = $("#timer").text();
    sec--;
    if (sec > -1) 
    {
        $.post(
        "ajax.php",
        {
            action : 'trecker'
        },
        function(data) {
            // Тут просто ежесекундная проверка данных
        });
    } else
    {
        $.post(
        "ajax/jgame.php",
        {
            action : 'auto'
        },
        function(data) {
            // Тут обновление таймера и вывод обработанных данных
        });
    }
}, 1000);
```

Помогите плиз, кто может

Comment: @Dzedzik, добро пожаловать в мир прогресса, безудержной оптимизации и заботы о пользователях. В фоновой вкладке таймауты неадекватят по-разному, где-то минимальный интервал секунда, где-то все просто замедляется, где-то, говорят, js замораживается.

В настройках вашего браузера это можно изменить, но у юзеров такое поведение по умолчанию.

(не добавляю ответ, т.к. подробностей не знаю и гуглить багрепорты лень)

Comment: @Sh4dow, вот этого как раз и боялся больше всего.. ну за ответ спасибо, буду тогда ломать голову что с этим делать